# Is it safe to use a BinaryReader and a BinaryWriter derived from the same stream source in separate threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, stream, tcpclient

I have a scenario with related but different questions. So it may look like a duplicated post but it’s not

I’m working on a class that uses a *TcpClient* eventually created on the UI thread to read and write data.  When the *TcpClient* is created the design is to connect to a server and create a *BinaryReader* and *BinaryWriter* immediately.

The *BinaryReader* is used on a dedicated thread that does a blocking read. When data arrives I generate an event and pass the data for processing. Rinse and repeat.

The *BinaryWriter* is used when data arrives on another thread. Right now it happens to be the UI thread, but it doesn’t have to be. One thing that is known is that it won’t be the same thread that the blocking reader is running.

Only one process will access either stream handler at a time so I don’t have to worry about two threads hitting the *BinaryWriter* at once, but locking will be added.

This is working, but since threading is hard I don’t want to just assume this is sound design. I have other questions concerning the lifetimes of them that will be asked separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty unclear, always post a snippet.  If they wrap the NetworkStream you get from TcpClient.GetStream() then there is no problem.  Explicitly mentioned in the MSDN article for NetworkStream:

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required.

Comment: I'm more interested in the concept than actual code in this case. I think your MSDN reference answers the question. But your comment about wrapping the NetworkStream it is only accessed when the Binaryxxxx are created. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything, it just wasn't clear what stream they read/write from.

Comment: Sorry. It came from the TcpClient. To be specific the GetStream() method.