# BinaryReader and BinaryWriter over NetworkStream

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to use a BinaryReader and BinaryWriter at the same time with the same underlying NetworkStream

1. using a single thread sequentially interlacing reads and writes?
2. using 1 thread for reading and 1 thread for writing?

(My goal is to simultaneously send and receive data via a TcpClient connection)

So far I've come across two related posts:

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840853/is-it-safe-to-use-a-binaryreader-and-a-binarywriter-derived-from-the-same-stream) references the [NetworkStream docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks):

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required.

The [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315316/asynchronous-binaryreader-and-binarywriter-in-net) references the [BinaryReader docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.basestream?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks):

> Using the underlying stream while reading or while using the BinaryReader can cause data loss and corruption. For example, the same bytes might be read more than once, bytes might be skipped, or character reading might become unpredictable.

I'm not 100% sure how to interpret these quotes and I'm not sure which of my 2 cases above are possible if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"yes" is the short answer; a `NetworkStream` essentially acts as a duplex stream, with the read operations completely separate to the write operations. A `BinaryReader` will only be using the read operations, and `BinaryWriter` the write operations. Concepts like `Length`, `Position` and `Seek` do not make sense on `NetworkStream` and are not supported. So: there should be no conflict here using `BinaryReader` / `BinaryWriter`. However, at the same time I would probably advise *against* using them - simply because they usually don't actually add much vs using raw `Stream` operations, and aren't compatible with arbitrary network protocols. If you're implementing something custom that just uses your code: you'll probably be fine, of course.

The warning about touching the `Stream` while using `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` still very much applies to some *other* streams - `FileStream` for example: you could trivially corrupt the data by repositioning the stream while a reader/writer thinks it is in charge - and since there is a single position: this means that reads will impact writes, etc. But: this simply doesn't apply to `NetworkStream`. In this regard: `NetworkStream` is the exception, not the rule: in terms of what you usually expect from a `Stream`, `NetworkStream` is very unusual.

Comment: _"use a BinaryReader and BinaryWriter **at the same time** "_ I read the question as such that "at the same time" is in the sense of "concurrently"...

Comment: @Fildor yup; and for most streams that would be bad; but `NetworkStream` *won't care*

Comment: Just saying because you didn't go into the "one thread with sequential read/write" vs "one thread for read and one for write" - part.

Comment: @Fildor right: I didn't; because *it doesn't matter here*

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks - I hadn't recognised that the warning on BinaryReader applied to streams in general. That clears up the apparent contradiction between the two quotes that was bothering me

Comment: @MarcGravell But won't blocking on a read make it impossible to write when using it in a "ping-pong" manner on one thread? (that is if there is nothing to read) Am I missing something?

Comment: If you stack reads and writes on the same thread, then obviously blocking on one will block the other as well. It's not blocking the *read* operation, it's blocking the *call* to the read operation. As Marc has said, the stream doesn't care but obviously code you write around it has to be written properly as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, that was exactly what I meant. That part of the question isn't addressed, imho.

Comment: @Fildor that is a separate concern that is unrelated to the issues in the question; whether or not that is a direct issue depends on the nature of the protocol you are consuming: I can see some cases where it would be 100% possible to implement a working API using a 
 single logical path, and other cases where you absolutely need separate read/write paths

Comment: Well, granted, the question is "**is it possible to** ...", not "**how do I properly write code to** ...", so the answer is still only "yes, this is possible." It is obviously also, in every scenario, possible to write broken code.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I was referring to the two options named in the upper part of the question. So I get that a "generic" answer or suggestion to that would be "depends on your protocol" ... and doesn't actually have much to do with the rest of the question.

Comment: The most important is BinaryReader/Writer not supports async.